# Ranging an elements in ObjectStorage TYPO3

Tags: arrays, object, file-upload, typo3

There is an object - an event that contains an array of images. Multiupload is used for uploading. The first image is used as the default preview. The Fluid file uses a radio-button to select any image from the array. The problem is that the selection is not saved.

As a solution option, there is an idea to move the selected element to the first position in the array.

```
public function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $p1 = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    $p2 = array_splice($array, 0, $b);
    $array = array_merge($p2,$p1,$array);
}
```

But here comes the problem of accessing the protected properties of ObjectStorage.

```
if (($arrayPos = $event->getMainImage()) !== 0) {
     $event->image->storage->moveElement(['storage'],$arrayPos,0);
   }
```

Is it possible to change the order of array elements and save? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be solved in multiple ways. But you have to consider the appropriate ways.

If you want to modify data in a way not considered yet you need to modify the Repository class so you can store the changes.

That could be an index ('which image should be used?'), where you need to have an additional field with it's setter and getter.

Or you have a function to reorder the images in an array.
Be aware that TYPO3 stores such information most times in mm-records. So you only need to to change the 'order' of the relations in the `sorting` field.

Comment: Thanks! I will try use an index.